# How to use Expression Language (EL) in a JavaScript/jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, el

How do you get a value from [Expression Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language#History) (EL) in a JSP to a JavaScript function?

In my JSP page I have:

```
<li>${state}</li>
<input title="Show ${state}">Show</>
```

And I would like to be able to get the `${state}` from the JSP into the JavaScript function:

```
$('#input').click(function() { 
if ($(this).val() == "Show + ${state}">") 
{ 
    $(this).val("Show"); 
    $(this).attr("title", "Hide + ${state}"> "); 
} 
else 
{ 
    $(this).val("Hide"); 
    $(this).attr("title", "Hide + ${state}">"); 
} 
});
```

I want for the title of each button to say show Ohio or Hide Ohio, but to change for whatever state is in the `<li>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

That JavaScript has to go in a `<script>` inside a `.jsp` file instead of a `.js` file in order to get JSP to inline the EL variables.

Alternatively, you can also just do a simple string-replace of the first word or a substring of the first four characters. This way you don't need any EL in the JavaScript and thus you can just put the JS code in its own `.js` file.

By the way, the logic flow of your whole function makes at its own very little sense. Don't you actually want to check if the `val()` is `"Hide"`? Don't you actually want to use `"Show"` in the title of one of the two conditions?

Comment: I would guess some of that is OP's testing code just to see which part of the `if` is actually running.

Answer (score 0):

If your possible values are going to be `Show ${State}` and `Hide ${State}` then you really only care about the first four characters:

```
if ($(this).val().substring(0, 4) == "Show")
{
    ...
}
...
```